# How to resize client size?

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi

I handle the WM_NCCALCSIZE message, and try to set the dest window client rect manually.

```
case WM_NCCALCSIZE: 
        {
            RECT *rect = (LPRECT)lParam;
            if (wParam == TRUE)
            {
                ////缩小客户区的范围
                //RECT *rect = (LPRECT)lParam;
                //rect-&gt;left += 8;
                //rect-&gt;right -= 8;
                //rect-&gt;top += 30;
                //rect-&gt;bottom = 8;
                InflateRect(rect, -50, -50);
                RECT dstRect = *(LPRECT)lParam;
                RECT srcRect = rect[1];
                rect[1] = dstRect;
                rect[2] = srcRect;

                //DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
                return 0;
                //return WVR_REDRAW;
            }
            else
            {
                DWORD lRet =  DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
                return lRet;
            }
```

But the result is bad, [image]
When I resize the window the text drawn with DrawText does not get erased cleanly.

How do I erase the background completely?

Comment: "The Hello Program": is that how you write "Hello, world" in Chinese? :) - Just kidding. Here (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632634(v=vs.85).aspx) it says you should return `WVR_REDRAW` to have the window redrawn, which I see you have commented out. Why?

Comment: @AndyProwl: becuase it does not work.

Comment: Check out the WM_NCCALCSIZE docs (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632634(VS.85).aspx) for an explanation of the various problems here... that message is rarely used enough that I'm guessing you don't actually need it. What are you actually trying to do here?

Comment: @HerrJoebob: resize the client rect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root cause here is if you changed the client size, you changed the non-client area size.
But WM_ERASEBKGND handler does only erase the client area background but not non-client area size.

So, if you changed the client size, you'll also need to handle the WM_NCPAINT to erase the non-client area background and paint the frame with DefWindowProc.